# Get the text content of an html element using xpath

Tags: html, xml, xpath, selenium-webdriver, xml-parsing

This is the html content

```
<p class="ref   Hover">
    <b class="Hover   Hover   Hover   Hover   Hover">Mfr Part#:</b>
    MC34063ADR2G<br>
   <b>Mounting Method:</b>&nbsp;
     Surface Mount<br>
   <b>Package Style:</b>&nbsp;
     SOIC-8<br>
  <b>Packaging:</b>&nbsp;
     REEL<br>
</p>
```

Using below xpath I am able to get only "Mfr Part#:".

```
//div[@id='product-desc']/p[2]/b[1]/text()
//div[@id='product-desc']/p[2]/b[1]
```

But I want "Mfr Part#:MC34063ADR2G"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MC34063ADR2G should be at

```
//div[@id='product-desc']/p[2]/text()[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`following-sibling`](http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example15.html) axis to get text the node following `<b>` element that you already managed to select, for example given the current context element is the `<b>` element :

```
following-sibling::text()[1]
```

or using full XPath :

```
//div[@id='product-desc']/p[2]/b[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use `//b[contains(@class, 'Hover')]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, hope it will help you

```
String text=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[contains(@class, 'Hover')]")).getText();
    String[] temp=text.split("\\bMounting\\b");
    System.out.println(temp[0]);
```